# Who was the One-Eyed King after all?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

In the Tokyo Ghoul:re manga, I just got confused at a most critical point. Takatsuki wanted Kaneki to fulfil her wish to 'kill the One-Eyed', but in the end, as far as I can make out, Arima was the One-Eyed King (or was he?). And the next page pictured Kaneki as the One-Eyed King. Can someone explain with references from the manga?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ch 86 Takatsuki implies, that Arima was real One-Eyed King (explanation behind the title is glaucoma - Arima was partially blind in one eye). Also, in Ch 89, Tatara also recalls Arima in his memories, and references him as "King". So, it is no doubt, that *Arima was real One-Eyed King*.

Once title becomes "vacant", Kaneki decides to claim it in the end of Ch 86 (we can suppose, he has full rights for it, since he defeated Arima). I believe, not so many people will question, if he is real One-Eyed King, since only several humans and ghouls were aware of One-Eyed King previous true identity.

As for now, it is not clear, what purpose Kaneki did this for, but this title for sure has some power and influence in world of TG.

Comment: I suppose this must be it. Thank you for your reply.